# Inconsistent NoSuchBeanDefinitionException since upgrading from Spring 3.0 to Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, autowired

We've been seeing inconsistent NoSuchBeanDefinitionException since upgrading from Spring 3.0 to Spring 3.1.  It happens to only about 2% of our hosts and even then the problem is not consistent in a single host since it might not happen after restarting the same server.

Here's the error :

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could 
not autowire field: private com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService 
com.amazon.ms3.container.impl.ExecutionEnvironmentImpl.functionThreadPool; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No matching bean of type [com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService] 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as 
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=functionThreadPool)} 
| at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation
             .AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues...
```

Here's the bean code (irrelevant code removed):

```
public class ExecutionEnvironmentImpl extends ExecutionEnvironment {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("functionThreadPool")
    private ListeningExecutorService functionThreadPool;

    public ExecutionEnvironmentImpl() {
    }

    public void setFunctionThreadPool(ListeningExecutorService functionThreadPool) {
        this.functionThreadPool = functionThreadPool;
    }

}
```

And here's the configuration file (irrelevant configuration removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
">

    <bean id="executionEnvironment" class="com.amazon.ms3.container.impl.ExecutionEnvironmentImpl" scope="prototype"/>

<!-- ThreadPool for executing tenant functions asynchronously -->
<bean id="functionThreadPool" class="com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors" factory-method="listeningDecorator">
    <constructor-arg>
         <bean class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" factory-method="newCachedThreadPool"/>                     
     </constructor-arg>
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

The Qualifier annotation isn't much of use anymore since we don't have other ListeningExecutorService defined but I don't believe it should be causing any problem.

Any ideas of what might be causing this? I've been thinking about removing the autowiring completely but I'd like to understand why this is happening in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your Spring config contain a `<context:annotation-config>` element? I don't see one in the snippet you provided - or did you remove that when you posted?

Comment: It does not. I played with it in the past and it wasn't making any difference so it was left out. Do you think it could help here?

Comment: Spring would need `<context:annotation-config>` to know that it should autowire the `functionThreadPool` into the `executionEnvironment`. I think the issue though is some sort of timing related issue. Will suggest an answer...

Comment: A coworker said he noticed a similar behavior when mixing XML and annotation and using prototype beans.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly some timing-related issue in the order that Spring brings up beans in the application context. It may be worth explicitly telling Spring to create the `functionThreadPool` first to ensure that it is available for autowiring into the `executionEnvironment`. To do that, you can use the `depends-on` attribute:

```
<bean id="executionEnvironment" 
      class="com.amazon.ms3.container.impl.ExecutionEnvironmentImpl" 
      scope="prototype"
      depends-on="functionThreadPool"/>

<!-- ThreadPool for executing tenant functions asynchronously -->
<bean id="functionThreadPool" class="com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors" factory-method="listeningDecorator">
    <constructor-arg>
         <bean class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" factory-method="newCachedThreadPool"/>                     
     </constructor-arg>
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

If you intend to use autowiring then you should have the `<context:annotation-config>` element in the configuration also - so that Spring knows to autowire the `functionThreadPool` into the `executionEnvironment`.

Comment: So I realized that the annotation post processor was set in another part of the program, which is why adding the <context:annotation-config> didn't change anything. Adding the depends-on might work but I feel it kinda defeats the purpose, might as well wire it directly instead. More reliable that way. I don't really want to add "depends-on" for every beans that get injected.

Comment: Agreed - and normally that wouldn't be necessary because Spring works out the dependency ordering before injection. But Spring may not be able to in this case - because the `ExecutionEnvironment` does not directly depend upon the `MoreExecutors` factory, rather it depends upon a side-effect - namely the production of the `ListeningExecutorService` object. Spring wouldn't be able to determine this automatically - so using `depends-on` would enforce it.

Comment: Actually functionThreadPool is not used anywhere else so I think I'll just declare it inside ExecutionEnvironment configuration. I'll let you know if it fixes it. I'm just afraid that a similar problem will pop up somewhere else in our configs.

Comment: That didn't work either. Even when wiring the bean directly we were still seeing issues sometimes. The only thing that solved it was removing the @Autowired annotation. It really weird.

Answer (score 0):

After trying depends-on and even wiring the bean directly like shown below :

```
<bean id="executionEnvironment" class="com.amazon.ms3.container.impl.ExecutionEnvironmentImpl" scope="prototype">
  <property name="functionThreadPool" ref="functionThreadPool"/>
</bean>

<!-- ThreadPool for executing tenant functions asynchronously -->
<bean id="functionThreadPool" class="com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors" factory-method="listeningDecorator">
    <constructor-arg>
         <bean class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" factory-method="newCachedThreadPool"/>                     
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

we were still seeing the same error on some occasions. The only thing that fixed it was to remove the @Autowired annotation in the ExecutionEnvironmentImpl class.

We didn't really fix the problem but more like avoiding it. I wish I could provide a better answer.